# Vue 3/Vue Router - Unplanned firing of onClick event listener

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

Working with Vue 3 and Vue Router. Event listeners work as planned on initial 'click' navigations, to and from Details.vue page. However, upon successive 'click' attempts, `hideDetails()` is immediately called without a perceived 'click' event.

---

***Home.vue***

```
<template>
    <main class="rounded">
        <item-one />
        <item-two />
    </main>
    <aside class="details__modal">
        <router-view></router-view>
    </aside>
</template>
```

***ItemOne.vue, ItemTwo.vue***

```
<template>
    <button @click="showDetails(id)">Item Name</button>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {showDetails} from '@/scripts/utils'
</script>
```

---

***Vue Router***

Details.vue is set up as a child of Home.vue. `addEventListener()` is called via global navigation guard.

```js
...
const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'home',
        component: Home,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'details',
                name: 'details',
                component: () =>
                    import(
                        /* webpackChunkName: "details" */ '../views/Details.vue'
                    ),
                props: route => route.params,
            },
        ],
    },
]

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes
})

router.afterEach(to => {
    if (to.name === 'details')
        document.addEventListener('click', handle_hideDetails)
})
```

---

***Details.vue***

On `showDetails()`, Details.vue is rendered as a child of Home.vue and displayed within a modal. If `props.id` does not exists, `hideDetails()` redirects to Home.vue. Before leaving page, `removeEventListener()` is called via the component navigation guard `onBeforeRouteLeave()`.

```
<template>
    <div class="details__wrapper">...</div
</template>

<script lang="ts">
...
export default defineComponent({
    props: {
        id: {
            type: String
        }
    },
    setup(props){
        if(!props.id) hideDetails()

        onBeforeRouteLeave(_ => document.removeEventListener('click', handle_hideDetails))
    }
})
</script>
```

---

***utils.ts***

All utility functions are here.

```js
import vm from '@/main'

export const handle_hideDetails = (e: Event): void => {
    const el = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector('div.details__wrapper')

    if (!e.composedPath().includes(el)) hideDetails()
}

export const showDetails = (id: string): void => {
    document.querySelector('aside.details__modal')?.classList.add('show')

    vm.$router.push({
        name: 'details',
        params: { id },
    })
}

export const hideDetails = (): void => {
    document.querySelector('aside.details__modal')?.classList.remove('show')
    setTimeout(() => vm.$router.push({ name: 'home' }), 2000)
}
```

Comment: The problem is you are attaching the `handle_hideDetails` to the document click event. So when you click to any element `handle_hideDetails` will be fired

Comment: @Duannx That's intentional. When the Details modal is open, any click on the page should fire the event to close the modal, with conditional routing. The listener is removed when navigating away from the page.

Comment: @Duannx It's on the successive clicks after the first where the modal immediately closes upon opening.

Comment: I believe the problem comes from that listener. Please reproduce your problem on a live code service like stackblitz or codesandbox so we can play with the code

Comment: @Duannx Issue was resolved by setting event listener useCapture to true. Still unsure why bubbling was only an issue for successive clicks, but at least now it's working.